# How I check if some attributes in the process/dataset are met or not?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am new in Python and want to make some data analysis :)

I have these columns in my dataset: date, material_code, vendor and price.

I would like to filter cases where I have for the same date and the same code and from the same vendor the different price.

I can think of some groupby function but don't know how to start.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you show your dataset? If you are new to python it's better to begin with lists, tuples and dictionaries and then use third party libraries like pandas.

Comment: Please post your code that you are struggling with. At the moment your question is too vague.

Comment: read the documentation of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), use subgroups or filter functions in the dataframe.